# Simplifying Time Input in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to make an idiot-proof rota planner for the managers at work, but I'm at an ends with how to simplify time input.

[image: Planner Image 1]

In `Time In` the managers want to write times quickly. For example, Luke works from 11 am until midnight. The managers want to enter `11` and it auto complete to `11:00`. When I test this, the time goes to `00:00` and the formula bar says the date is using the `11`, rather than the time:
[image: Time Issue]

How would I go about fixing this issue?

P.S I already have the format set to `hh:mm`

Comment: This bugged me for a while as well. I don't think there is a simpler way unless you write some Excel VBA backend or some thing that takes 
inputs as numbers and converts them to a time cell next to it.

Comment: Type `11:`. If the problem is that the `:` is reachable only using `Shift` key, then you could use [AutoCorrect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-AutoCorrect-options-for-capitalization-spelling-and-symbols-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to replace two dots `..` with `:`. When done so you can type `11..` and it will be converted to `11:`.

Comment: Do you consider to put VBA code which will validate it during input? You would need to ensure that people using it will have macros enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

(For example) - In cell H2 , put a formula =C2/24   and format this cell as Custom - hh:mm  either with AM/PM   or without that.

Now when the user enters 11 in cell C2, the cell H2 will convert to 11:00:00

If the user wants to enter 11:30 as time-in (in cell H3) then the user should key-in 11.5 in cell C3.